# Can you use the App Engine socket package for websockets?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to support websockets on the Go runtime for Google App Engine (in the standard environment). People in other threads have pointed to the sockets package, but I can't see how you'd use it for a websocket. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application running in the standard environment can use the [gorilla/websocket](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) package as a client.  Set the [Dialer.NetDial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.NetDial) function to `func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) { return socket.Dial(ctx, network, addr) }` where `socket` is the appengine socket package. Set other dialer fields as needed and call [Dialer.Dial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.Dial) to dial the connection.

An application running in the standard environment cannot serve websocket connections.

Comment: For clarification - when you say client connections are supported, does that mean that my App Engine application can act as a client to another websocket server? i.e. cannot be a websocket server where a JavaScript frontend connected to it?